# Sqlalchemy Error when running initdb on Airflow 1.10.9

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

Recently we upgraded to Airflow 1.10.10 and downgraded back to 10.10.9. Now when running airflow initdb I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "operator" of relation "task_instance" already exists

[SQL: ALTER TABLE task_instance ADD COLUMN operator VARCHAR(1000)]
```

We are running the DB on postgresql and running resetdb isn't an option. I've tried upgradedb as well and switching airflow version but can't seem to see a way around this unless I fiddle around with the postgres database which could lead to more errors when initializing. Any help or tips is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: I am getting this similar error too.